# After setting the firebase I get the following error: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, firebase-security

I just want to install the firbase as database, but contantly getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: permission_denied at /courses: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at errorForServerCode (index.cjs.js:647)
    at onComplete (index.cjs.js:9114)
    at Object.onComplete (index.cjs.js:12681)
    at index.cjs.js:11797
    at PersistentConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:12052)
    at Connection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:11337)
    at Connection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (index.cjs.js:11331)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (index.cjs.js:11232)
    at WebSocketConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (index.cjs.js:10837)
    at WebSocketConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (index.cjs.js:10887)
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ]
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private _db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.courses = this._db.list('/courses').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Just installed by

```
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
```

didn't help

```
npm install firebase-tools --save
firebase login
firebase init
```

didn't help too

file database.rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

tab 'rules' on console.firebase.google.com site

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me how to install correctly the firebase in Angular 6

Answer (score 8):

You've set the security rules for the **Cloud Firestore** database. But your code is trying to read from the **Firebase Realtime Database**. The two databases are completely separate, and use different security rules to control access.

To allow read/write access to your `/courses` node in the realtime database, go the [security rules for the realtime database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/_/rules) and use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "courses": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On site console.firebase.google.com in the Database tab I selected Realtime Database instead of Cloud Firestore (beta) which was the default.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this error appears after you write the "Firebase deploy" command in the console. If this is some kind of training project, then just manually change the security rules to the states of "read: true" and "write: true"

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase auth there is a great method which allows users to sign anonymusly before they actually sign in.

First include the script for auth module after firebase script like this:

```
     <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Then in your js or script use this code:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
```